# composer says that zend-serviccemanager 2.7.8 conflicts with zendframework 2.4.0

Tags: php, zend-framework, composer-php, zend-framework2

I have a legacy system that I have to mantain and at moment I can't update it to newest technologys

But i'm facing problems with AWS S3, and trying some things, I decided to reinstall the dependencies, but now, I receive a message that says that zendservicemanager was replaced by zendframework, but I used this composer.json for years without this problem, and the two services are abandoned... do anyone have a hint please?

This is my composer.json

```
{
    "name" : "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description" : "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "require" : {
        "php" : ">=5.4",
        "zendframework/zendframework" : "2.4.*@stable",
        "phpmd/phpmd" : ">=1.4.1",
        "dompdf/dompdf" : "~0.6.2",
        "marcelojeff/php-sdk" : "dev-master",
        "imagine/imagine" : "~0.5.0",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php-zf2" : "~2.0",
        "neitanod/forceutf8" : "dev-master",
        "elasticsearch/elasticsearch" : "~2.3",
        "zfcampus/zf-oauth2" : "~1.3",
        "nicolab/php-ftp-client" : "^1.2",
        "twig/twig" : "~1.0",
        "leafo/scssphp" : "^0.6.6",
        "zendframework/zend-servicemanager" : "2.7.8",
        "cocur/slugify" : "^2.3",
        "twig/extensions" : "^1.5",
        "layershifter/tld-extract" : "dev-master",
        "google/apiclient" : "^2.0",
        "disal/rox": "dev-master"
    },
    "keywords" : [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "minimum-stability" : "dev",
    "license" : "BSD-3-Clause",
    "homepage" : "http://framework.zend.com/"
}
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the error messages you are facing and the attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: `"zendframework/zendframework" : "2.4.*@stable",` - wow, that would install dependencies that are more than five years old. I would highly recommend starting to upgrade your application. I don't want to know how many security issues the dependencies you are currently using open in your application